# Reading a .conf file PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am stuck and hoping someone can help me out. I am trying to read a .conf file in PHP to get some variables.

My file is in this format:

```
class: English
room: 150e
```

How can I go about getting the value from class or room?

Comment: `file()` `foreach()` `explode()`

Comment: Loop through the lines in the file, split each line at `:`, and create an associative array whose keys are the first element and values are the second element.

Comment: I'd recommend you try doing something for yourself and come here when you have problems. You'll learn more that way.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$file = 'yourfile.conf';
$contents = file($file);
foreach($contents as $line) {
    $e = explode(':', $line);
    $conf[trim($e[0])] = trim($e[1]);
}
```

Now you have an array with your configurations.